# Based on relevant experience, what are some good laptop recommendations for someone studying data engineering and is intending to get AWS certified?

Tags: laptop, pc

My friend has recently started studying a university program in data engineering and is intending to get AWS certified. They are planning on taking various related courses and boot camps to further sharpen their skills and are going to delve into this field in the near future.

They asked me for recommendations about a ***Windows-based*** laptop for their study and normal day-to-day use, but after some research, I felt like I didn't have the necessary experience in the field to provide a definitive answer without consulting more experienced people.

My friend is in Germany, and they prefer a laptop in the range of 1500 EUR to 2500 EUR that can serve them for a couple of years.

Thanks in advance for taking the time to help. Your contribution is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a laptop that will last, get a [framework](https://frame.work/). If you want the best price, customize an option from Dell, HP, or Lenovo.

Slimbook and System76 both make good laptops if you want Linux native. I understand if that's not the direction you want to go, but for that job, you will defiantly want to get familiar with Linux.

If you are going to start working with AWS, your laptop's specs are not very important. The vast majority of your work will be done server side.